# angular5 style background color based on condition

Tags: angular, cell

I have a material mat table and the cell has a conditional.  What I need to do is color the cell if the condition is true.

```
<div>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="Value">
       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Value </mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let record" style="text-align:center"> {{record.Value == -1 ?  'N/A' : record.Value }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
 </div>
```

I need only to have the N/A colored red otherwise no color.  Any help would be appreciated.  I have tried to wrap the binding with style.background-color="'red'"  binding condition  without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try :

```
<div>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="Value">
       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Value </mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let record" [class.red]="record.Value == -1" style="text-align:center"> {{record.Value == -1 ?  'N/A' : record.Value }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
 </div>
```

and

```
mat-cell.red {
    background-color: red;
    align-self: stretch; // so the cell take all the height
    line-height: 48px; // for vertical align of content if you are with the default cell height
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely as well as provides css access.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a conditional style with `[ngStyle]`:

```
<div>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="Value">
       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Value </mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let record" style="text-align:center" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':record.Value == -1 ? 'red' : 'transparent' }"> {{record.Value == -1 ?  'N/A' : record.Value }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
 </div>
```